# Is it possible to embed SSRS ReportViewer in VB6 program?

Tags: vb6, reportviewer, reporting-services

My team is looking for a manner to embed SSRS Report Viewer into a currently working VB6 program as the replacement of Crystal Report. Is it possible? if so, and how?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about that, but you can certainly use a different approach such as:
Build a .NET WinForms program (exe) that uses the SSRS Report Viewer control and just call it with a VB6 Shell() + the parameter(s) of the report to run.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of however another option would be to use a canned web browser control on a VB6 form and call the report using its URL

Comment: What about if local report is used?